# VSTS Xamarin.iOS build tasks define multiple constants using /p:DefineConstants

Tags: c#, xamarin, msbuild, azure-devops, conditional-compilation

I'm using the Xamarin.iOS build task in VSTS to build my solution.
I want to define the constants `ENABLE_ANALYTICS` and `ENV_DEV`.

Unfortulately, I can't figure out what to enter in the `Arguments` input field to get it run successfully. I'm using the `Hosted macOS Preview` build agent and `msbuild (Visual Studio for Mac)` build tool.

**I tried:**

`/p:DefineConstants=ENABLE_ANALYTICS;ENV_DEV`

> MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid.
>
> Switch: ENV_DEV

`/p:DefineConstants="ENABLE_ANALYTICS;ENV_DEV"`

> MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid.
>
> Switch: ENV_DEV

`/p:DefineConstants='ENABLE_ANALYTICS;ENV_DEV'`

> MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid.
>
> Switch: ENV_DEV'

`/p:DefineConstants=""ENABLE_ANALYTICS;ENV_DEV""`

> MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid.
>
> Switch: ENV_DEV

`'/p:DefineConstants=""ENABLE_ANALYTICS;ENV_DEV"'`

> MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
>
> Switch: '/p:DefineConstants=ENABLE_ANALYTICS;ENV_DEV'

Comment: Aren't you better defining a new configuration for your solution instead? So instead of just `Debug` and `Release`, you also have `Foo`.

Comment: I wanted to avoid to create a configuration for each permutation of all constants :(

Comment: And instead you'll have a multitude of build definitions in VSTS?

Comment: Hmm maybe you are right. I should rethink that. Let me try.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe Can you share the project file and detail vsts build log (by setting `system.debug` as `true`)? And what's the Build Configuration did you use? If you use `Release` for Build Configuration, please try to build again with  `Debug` Build Configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem was the build script was trimming out all double quotes unless they were escaped. And the escaping algorithm appeared to be not quite trivial. [That is the function doing that](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/efd45f979f5a2be4f4fc689a0b1dc4540d160a47/Tests-Legacy/lib/vsts-task-lib/toolrunner.ts#L67).

```js
for (var i=0; i < argString.length; i++) {
    var c = argString.charAt(i);

        if (c === '"') {
            if (!escaped) {
                inQuotes = !inQuotes;
            }
            else {
                append(c);
            }
            continue;
        }
                
        if (c === "\\" && inQuotes) {
            escaped = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (c === ' ' && !inQuotes) {
            if (arg.length > 0) {
            args.push(arg);
            arg = '';
        }
        continue;
    }
    append(c);
}
```

so to keep the double quotes in the resulted string it should look like that:

```
/p:DefineConstants="\"A;B\"
```

When using it for `XamariniOS` task:

```yaml
- task: XamariniOS@2
  inputs:
    ...
    args: '/p:DefineConstants="\"A;B\"'
```

As a bonus, here's an example of the pipeline script allowing you to select constants to include via the "Run Pipeline" UI

[image: run pipeline ui]

```yaml
parameters:
- name: ENABLE_DEBUG_ERROR_MESSAGES
  displayName: 'Enable debug error messages'
  type: boolean
  default: true
- name: ENABLE_MOCK_API_OPTION
  displayName: 'Enable mock API option'
  type: boolean
  default: true

trigger:
- develop

variables:
- ${{ each p in parameters }}:
  - name: "DEFINECONSTANT_${{p.key}}"
    value: ${{ p.value }}

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:
- pwsh: |
    $constantVars = Get-ChildItem -Path Env:\ | Where-Object Name -like "DEFINECONSTANT_ENABLE_*"
    $constantList = "/p:DefineConstants=`"\`""
    $constantVars | ForEach-Object {
      if ($_.Value -eq 'True') {
        $constantList += "$($_.Name.Replace('DEFINECONSTANT_', ''));"
      }
    }
    $constantList += "\`""
    Write-Host $constantList
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=define]$constantList"

- bash: echo 'My pipeline variable is $(define)'

- task: XamariniOS@2
  inputs:
    solutionFile: 'YOUR_SOLUTION.sln'
    configuration: 'Release'
    packageApp: false
    buildForSimulator: true
    runNugetRestore: false
    args: '$(define)'
```

P.S. Thanks to @WaitingForGuacamole for assistance in writing the script above in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66262564/create-msbuild-arguments-string-based-on-a-set-of-boolean-parameters/66265670).

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to escape the semi-colon:

`/p:DefineConstants=ENABLE_ANALYTICS\;ENV_DEV`

Comment: Doesn't work either. `MSBUILD : error MSB1005: Specify a property and its value.`

Answer (score -1):

I've run into a similar problem and I've solved it by adding the constants twice

```
/p:DefineConstants=ENABLE_ANALYTICS /p:DefineConstants=ENV_DEV
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. It applies only the last constant.