# Create MSBuild arguments string based on a set of boolean parameters

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

As a AzureDevops user I want to be able to manually pass different MSBuild constants (via `DefineConstants`) by turning checkboxes on and off on the "Run Pipeline" UI.
Example:

[image: pipeline-settings]

I achieve that by defining two boolean parameters for the current pipeline:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: enableDebugErrorMessages
  displayName: 'Enable debug error messages'
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: enableAnalytics
  displayName: 'Enable analytics'
  type: boolean
  default: true
```

Now I want to generate a string for MSBuild containing enabled constants. Examples:

```
/p:DefineConstants="ENABLE_ANALYTICS"
/p:DefineConstants="ENABLE_DEBUG_MESSAGES;ENABLE_ANALYTICS"
```

so I can pass them for MSBuild this way:

```
- task: XamariniOS@2
  inputs:
    args: '<HERE>'
```

I've tried all possible combination of expressions from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) I could think of except [I want to do something that is not supported by expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#i-want-to-do-something-that-is-not-supported-by-expressions-what-options-do-i-have-for-extending-pipelines-functionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**: I took (**another**) crack at it on a trivial pipeline and came up with this:

```
pool: MyBuildPool

parameters:
- name: ENABLE_ANALYTICS
  displayName: "Analytics"
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: ENABLE_DEBUG_MESSAGES
  displayName: "Debug Messages"
  type: boolean
  default: true
- name: ENABLE_SOMETHING_ELSE
  displayName: "Something Else"
  type: boolean
  default: false

variables:
- ${{ each p in parameters }}:
  - name: "DEFINECONSTANT_${{p.key}}"
    value: ${{ p.value }}
  
steps:
- pwsh: |
    $constantVars = Get-ChildItem -Path Env:\ | Where-Object Name -like "DEFINECONSTANT_*"
    $constantList = ""
    $constantVars | ForEach-Object {
        $constantList += "$($_.Name.Replace('DEFINECONSTANT_', ''))=$($_.Value);"
    }
    Write-Host "/p:DefineConstants=`"$constantList`""
  displayName: 'Combine parameter values'
```

When I have Azure Pipelines expand **that** file, I get:

```
parameters:
- name: ENABLE_ANALYTICS
  displayName: "Analytics"
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: ENABLE_DEBUG_MESSAGES
  displayName: "Debug Messages"
  type: boolean
  default: true
- name: ENABLE_SOMETHING_ELSE
  displayName: "Something Else"
  type: boolean
  default: false
variables:
- name: DEFINECONSTANT_ENABLE_ANALYTICS
  value: False
- name: DEFINECONSTANT_ENABLE_DEBUG_MESSAGES
  value: True
- name: DEFINECONSTANT_ENABLE_SOMETHING_ELSE
  value: False
stages:
- stage: __default
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    pool:
      name: MyPoolName
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Combine parameter values'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          $constantVars = Get-ChildItem -Path Env:\ | Where-Object Name -like "DEFINECONSTANT_*"
          $constantList = ""
          $constantVars | ForEach-Object {
              $constantList += "$($_.Name.Replace('DEFINECONSTANT_', ''))=$($_.Value);"
          }
          Write-Host "/p:DefineConstants=`"$constantList`""
        pwsh: true
```

Is that closer to what you want? You can have checkboxes with different constant names, descriptions, and default values.

Comment: Thank for the hint of using pwsh for this. I've improved your example a little bit by setting the final variable with `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=defineConstants]$constantList"` to use it for msbuild.

Comment: That seems like a perfectly reasonable enhancement - you could also have checkboxes driving different option flags (say it's not just `DefineConstants`) by having multiple prefixes. This was actually a fun one to work on, because it bumped right up against known limitations in Azure Pipelines where array variable types are not supported (I wanted to enumerate the parameters into a single array variable and `join` it), and where `${{ each }}` cannot be used within a string (I wanted to enumerate the parameters directly into the option string). This forced me to consider a creative workaround.

Comment: Right. On top for all other challenges Azure's yaml syntax has it also has all sort of problems when it comes to arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [If expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) to set the value of the corresponding variable based on the value of the boolean parameter.

Here is the sample:

```
variables:
   ${{ if and(parameters.enableDebugErrorMessages, 'true', ne(parameters.enableAnalytics, 'true')) }}: 
     DefineConstants: ENABLE_DEBUG_MESSAGES 
   ${{ if and(parameters.enableDebugErrorMessages, 'true', eq(parameters.enableAnalytics, 'true')) }}: 
     DefineConstants: ENABLE_DEBUG_MESSAGES;ENABLE_ANALYTICS
   ${{ if and(parameters.enableAnalytics, 'true', ne(parameters.enableDebugErrorMessages, 'true')) }}: 
     DefineConstants: ENABLE_ANALYTICS


parameters:
- name: enableDebugErrorMessages
  displayName: 'Enable debug error messages'
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: enableAnalytics
  displayName: 'Enable analytics'
  type: boolean
  default: true

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest


steps:
...
```

In MSbuild argument, you could use the following format: `/p:DefineConstants= "$(DefineConstants)"`.

> select enableDebugErrorMessages -> $(DefineConstants) =
> ENABLE_DEBUG_MESSAGES
>
> select enableAnalytics -> $(DefineConstants) = ENABLE_ANALYTICS
>
> select both -> $(DefineConstants) =
> ENABLE_DEBUG_MESSAGES;ENABLE_ANALYTICS

Comment: Imagine how many combinations I'll have to add when I add a couple of more parameters.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But the boolean parameter can't set the string value, so you need to set the corresponding value through parameter judgment. As far as I know, there is  no easier method. Thanks

Comment: Kevin, I think this is a perfect use case to take back to the development team as an argument to support array variables. Then, the script could use `${{ each p in parameters }}:` and then an `${{ if }}` on `p.key` to determine if it is part of a "group", and then emit values into a single array variable (which could be `${{ join }}ed` later in the script!